# Issues running Koans in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I am attempting to run Koans in PyCharm.  I have downloaded all of the necessary programs.  I have attempted to open the "contemplate_koans" file in pycharm but it responds with the following message:

```
import unittest
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
        print("\nThis is the Python 3 version of Python Koans, but you are " +
            "running it with Python 2!\n\n"
            "Did you accidentally use the wrong python script? \nTry:\n\n" +
            "    python3 contemplate_koans.py\n")
    else:
        if sys.version_info < (3, 3):
            print("\n" +
                "********************************************************\n" +
                "WARNING:\n" +
                "This version of Python Koans was designed for " +
                "Python 3.3 or greater.\n" +
                "Your version of Python is older, so you may run into " +
                "problems!\n\n" +
                "But lets see how far we get...\n" +
                "********************************************************\n")

        from runner.mountain import Mountain

        Mountain().walk_the_path(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm to take you literally on this, looks like you opened the file for editing rather than executing it with Python. You either need to figure out how to execute it rather than open it from PyCharm, or just run it from the command line.

Instructions for running it from the command line with Python can be found in the project the project instructions, under the "Getting Started" section:

https://github.com/gregmalcolm/python_koans/blob/master/README.rst